# res:// prefix for Image tag does not load the correct size of the image in Native Script (android)

Tags: android, image, nativescript

Designed images for the maximum resolution and used Native script image builder for the drawable assets and placed them correctly , but on Nexus 5X API 23 emulator , it displays an image that is even larger than the maximum size of the image.

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="bg-background"> 
<Image src="res://careers_btn"></Image> 
</StackLayout>
```

[image: xxxhdpi image]

[image: image which the emulator displays]

Answer (score 0):

This is what needs to be added

```
 <Image src="res://careers_btn" stretch="none"></Image>
```